# angular cli: ng build --bh on IIS not finding stylesheets

Tags: angularjs, build, angular-cli

I'm having troubles trying to deploy an angular 2 app using angular-cli.

the app is to be found at "http://DomainName/AppName".  In IIS, a web application ('AppName') under the 'DomainName' web is pointing to 'dist'.

the closest i've come to getting it working is to use "ng build --bh /AppName/", or 'nb build --bh .'...

However, this doesn't *quite* work, because even though the components seem to be working, the stylesheets aren't loading... f12 reveals that the browser is getting 404s when trying to get to things like:

...DomainName/AppName/include/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/boostrap.min.css

The application renders just fine when using ng serve and going to localhost:4200.

I'm using beta 22...

Any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should add your 3rd party css in angular-cli.json under `apps[0].styles`, not by linking them from index.html

`ng build` will bundle your css-files to your dist-folder

Something like this:

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
  "styles.css"
],
```

More info here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation

If you want your "include" folder to be part of the build make sure it's in the assets-array in angular-cli.json

```
"assets": [
        "include",
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above fix but it didn't work.  What did work was adding a href link into the index.html file that pointed to my additional stylesheet. e.g. 
`<link href="/assets/AngularStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Crude but effective.